# control characters in php file handling

Tags: php

I'm trying to write the £ symbol to a file using PHP. However when I open the file I have created the £ sign is always preceded with the symbol `¬` (on my keyboard this is an alt L)

Is there anyway to suppress this?

```
$file=fopen($lastid,'w');
echo $file;
fwrite($file, "

    Date: $receipt_date
    Customer: $customer
    Receipt number: $id
    Description: $description


    Amount: £$NET
    VAT: £$VAT
    Total: £$gross

    test:£500

    Payment received with thanks by $payment


    UNIQUECAPTURE VAT:");
fclose($file);
```

Comment: You could try to `utf8_encode("the string")`

Comment: It seems like you've discovered PHP's poor support for multibyte character encodings! You've a long and painful road ahead, and I'm sorry to say it's all downhill from here.

Comment: Before anybody says any more about PHP and encodings, read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding) @Quasdunk

Comment: @Charlie That's a completely nonsensical generalization.

Comment: @Charlie - For me that code works well, with default PHP configuration. IMHO it's not problem with PHP.

Comment: @Pawel: I would say it's most definitely a PHP problem if the same code produces different results on two different machines.

Comment: @Charlie That would be because Paweł's browser is interpreting the site he saved with the correct encoding. Go to the View menu in your browser right now and switch the encoding to ISO-8859-1 to see the exact same problem on this very page. **It's not a PHP problem at all.** Please stop spreading the pointless opinion that PHP's Unicode handling is poor and read my aforelinked article. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi guys with a little help from my grandfather i found a way around it simply by adding

```
    $input = str_replace("£", "&pound;", $input);
```

the pound symbol is now shown as `£`
heres the final code

```
$input = str_replace("£", "&pound;", $input);     
$file=fopen($lastid. $dash. $customer,'w');
```

Many thanks for all your help

for some reason the second `£` symbol is meant to be an `&pound`

Comment: Unfortunately you have missed the opportunity to learn something about encodings.

Answer (score 2):

That means the source code file is saved using a different encoding than the program you're opening it with is trying to interpret it with. Most likely your source code is saved as UTF-8 (and therefore the text written to the file is UTF-8) and the program is trying to read it as ISO-8859-1. `£` in UTF-8 is `0xC2 0xA3`, in ISO-8859-1 `¬` is `0xC2` and `£` is `0xA3`. Make sure the program you're trying to open it with is intelligent enough to recognize UTF-8 when it sees it or explicitly tell it to interpret the file using UTF-8.

Shameless self-promotion, because it's about exactly this topic: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding)